# Why ServiceStack.Redis store stuck my Visual Studio

Tags: caching, redis, servicestack

Im new to Redis. I completly installed two instances of Redis , one master one slave.

i tested some insert/get functions with simple "1" as key and "Hello from Redis" as value. I also tested with some simple class like

```
public class Test{

public Guid ID{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}

}
```

But when i implemented in my project and when i try to store some call from DB, client stuck. My CPU is 30% and Visual Studio dont response if i dont close debug webserver from task manager.

My code is

```
 var  FromDB = db.Profiles.SingleOrDefault(p => p.UserID == UserID);

 var client = new RedisClient("ip", 6379).As<Profile>();

 client.Store(FromDB);
```

When i close Visual Studio from task manager, i get this error 
[image]

When i try to store simple key/value, everything works

```
var client = new RedisClient("ip",6379);

bool success = client.Set("4", new Test{ID = new Guid(), Name ="Value"});
```

I`m totally new to Redis and maybe i make simple mistake..

I have debug points before and after this code, my code never get after this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your models you use are "clean POCOs" that don't have any cyclical relationships.

So if `Profiles` is a Data Model, you need to map it to a clean DTO without cyclical deps.

Comment: That was the problem :). Solved!